# Matrix for zeroing specific entries.

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Is there a matrix, $X$, that can be solved-for here?

$
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & b & c \\ 
d & e & f \\   
g & h & i 
\end{array}\right) X = 
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & b & c \\ 
d & e & 0 \\   
0 & h & i 
\end{array}\right)
 $

I want a given $3\times3$ matrix to be transformed into the one above, with $a,f,$ and $g$ eliminated.

Comment: Is it principal for you to use transform by right-hand multiplying on the matrix $X$ or you may use a bit more complex transformation?

Comment: Either side is fine. I'm just looking for $f$, where $f(A) = B$ , so $f(A) = X A$ would be fine.

Answer (score 2):

If $a,b,\ldots,i$ are nice so the LHS is invertible, set
$$
X = 
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c \\ 
d & e & f \\   
g & h & i 
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & b & c \\ 
d & e & 0 \\   
0 & h & i 
\end{pmatrix}
$$